# Order and mode in page allocation failure

Tags: linux, kernel

Can anyone help me in understanding of what "order" and "mode" parameter notate in a kernel error of page allocation failure.

Answer (score 3):

Mode is the [gfp_flags](http://kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html) passed with the allocation request, and specifies the requested behavior of the memory allocator (GFP_KERNEL, GFP_ATOMIC,...). Order is the log of number of pages requested from the allocator, e.g., order is 1 for 2 page requests, or 4 when 16 pages are requested.

Also see [2](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/gfp.h) if you want to try to make a mapping.